# Bluetooth issue on iPhone with iOS 10

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, ios

After I updated my iPhone 6 to iOS 10 I started having issues with calls using the Parrot MKi9200 Bluetooth car kit.

When I am talking on the phone through the Bluetooth kit the connection keeps dropping. Every minute or so it tells me that the connection was lost, and after a few seconds it connects again. This happens both when I am using regular phone calls and VoIP calls. However, when I am playing music or streaming a YouTube video there are no issues.

Most of the websites that talk about Bluetooth problems on iOS 10 suggest resetting the network settings. I have done this as well as re-pairing the Bluetooth device, but neither has helped my situation.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with my bluetooth hearing aids. I spent 2 1/2 hours on the phone with Apple senior tech support. They have a problem. They could only collect data from me. They dont have an answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

***I have phoned Parrot and it is an Apple softwear problem due to the software update. Ring Parrot and they will talk you through how to reset your phone settings and the Parrot.

***I have the exact same problem between iPhone 6 with upgraded ios10 and the Parrot MKi9200 car kit.

Seems the bluetooth problem is with the iPhone 6 and Apple do not have a fix yet. The MKi9200 seems to be working in every other way and only caused difficulty immediately after iPhone upgrade to ios 10. Apple have not confirmed yet and seem to be ignoring this issue as they do not have any announcement.

Meanwhile, try plugging extra cables to convert to USB for plugging into the wired connection - hopefully this helps you - it takes a few extra cables and converter male to female. Answer just now until Apple get their finger out and fix the problem they created. Just wish Apple and Microsoft test everything prior to release. A lot of people using the same kit.

All the best.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  Flagging for removal as not an answer. - From Review

Comment: @fbara - there is actually a workaround in the post.  The OP was giving background info when he said that he had "the exact same problem."

Comment: @Allan yea, I can see that. I flagged it because it didn't address the problem the OP was having, which was bluetooth cutting out.  Giving a workaround is ok but it should've been done in a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @fbara - a workaround can be and is often times,  an acceptable solution.